# Why mongo doesn't use the right index?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB to store data with the following structure :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a497a1f451bf00880331913"), "device" : "deviceId", "topic" : "topicId", "vhost" : "vhostId", "date" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:31.220Z"), "value" : 452 }
```

with the following indexes :

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "thingsplay.data"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "device" : 1,
                        "topic" : 1,
                        "date" : 1
                },
                "name" : "device_1_topic_1_date_1",
                "ns" : "thingsplay.data",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "device" : 1,
                        "topic" : 1,
                        "vhost" : 1
                },
                "name" : "device_1_topic_1_vhost_1",
                "ns" : "thingsplay.data",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

But when I'm making a query with device, topic and date fields it uses device_1_topic_1_vhost_1 index...

For another request with the explain option I just had the right winning plan (device_1_topic_1_date_1) but when I execute it... I'm still waiting for it to complete and with `db.currentOp()` I don't see it using any index...

```
{
        "desc" : "conn2172",
        "threadId" : "2836",
        "connectionId" : 2172,
        "client" : "x.x.x.x:50177",
        "appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
        "clientMetadata" : {
                "application" : {
                        "name" : "MongoDB Shell"
                },
                "driver" : {
                        "name" : "MongoDB Internal Client",
                        "version" : "3.6.2"
                },
                "os" : {
                        "type" : "Windows",
                        "name" : "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2",
                        "architecture" : "x86_64",
                        "version" : "6.1 SP1 (build 7601)"
                }
        },
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : 22137990,
        "secs_running" : 322,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(322246758),
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "company.data",
        "query" : {
                "explain" : {
                        "find" : "data",
                        "filter" : {
                                "device" : "deviceId",
                                "topic" : "topicId",
                                "date" : {
                                        "$gt" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"),

                                        "$lt" : ISODate("2018-06-12T16:18:00Z")
                                }
                        }
                },
                "verbosity" : "executionStats"
        },
        "numYields" : 19245,
        "locks" : {
                "Global" : "r",
                "Database" : "r",
                "Collection" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(38492)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(19246)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(19246)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I don't understand why the index is not being used...

Comment: You have vhost in the query as well. Apparently query planner decided this index is more efficient.

Comment: What's your query?

Comment: @AlexBlex No I don't specify the vhost in the query... That's why I don't understand why it uses that index...

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I don't have the specific query for the example but it is one that look like : db.data.find({ device:"deviceId", topic:"topicId", date:{ $gt:ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt:ISODate("2018-06-13T12:00:00.000Z") } })

Comment: Fair enough. Could you provide result of explain with `allPlansExecution` stats?